# PUT cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Consider the following Rest controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method = PUT, path = "/orders/{oid}")
    public void PendingPO(Model model, @RequestParam(name = "id") Long id) throws Exception {
         salesService.PendingPurchaseOrder(PurchaseOrderID.of(id));       
    }
```

The problem is, in `method = PUT` it complains that:

```
PUT cannot be resolved to a variable
```

So i dob't know how can make a controller method for http method of PUT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to introduce static import for PUT:

```
import static org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.PUT.
```

Or make usual import of RequestedMethod enum and use reference to PUT: RequestMethod.PUT.